# AMOUNT_ERROR when redirecting to PayPal - old PayPal script

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to update an old script that uses PayPal to checkout.  The `$auth_token` variable is equal to my business account's identity token.

```
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'receipt')
{
    $request = 'cmd=_notify-synch';
    $tx_token = $_REQUEST['tx'];
    $auth_token = $configtoken;
    $request .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$headerx .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$headerx .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$headerx .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$headerx .= "Content-Length: " . strlen ($request) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $sock = fsockopen('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$sock)
    {
        $file = fopen($config['log'] . $_REQUEST['tx'] . '.datatrans', "w", 0);
        fputs($file, "HTTP ERROR\n");
        fclose($file);
        eval('$cartinfo .= "' . fetch_template('covercart_orderfailure') . '";');
    } else
    {
        fputs($sock, $headerx . $request);
        // read the body data
        $result = '';
        $headerdone = false;

        while (!feof($sock))
        {
            $line = fgets($sock, 1024);

            if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0)
            {
                // read the header
                $headerdone = true;
            } else
                if ($headerdone)
                {
                    // header has been read. now read the contents
                    $result .= $line;
                }
        }

        // parse the data
        $lines = explode("\n", $result);
        $keyarray = array();

        if (!strcmp($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0)
        {
            $file = fopen($config['log'] . $_REQUEST['tx'] . '.datatrans', "w", 0);
            fputs($file, "COULD NOT VALIDATE\n");
            fclose($file);
            eval('$cartinfo .= "' . fetch_template('covercart_orderfailure') . '";');
        } else
        {
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($lines); $i++)
            {
                list($key, $val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
                $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
            }
            $txn_id = $keyarray['txn_id'];
            $item_name = $keyarray['item_name'];
            $item_number = $keyarray['item_number'];

            $payment_status = $keyarray['payment_status'];
            $payer_email = $keyarray['payer_email'];

            $product = explode("|", $item_number);
            $item_array = explode("-", $product[1]);
            $transamount = $_REQUEST['amt'];
            $cm = urldecode($_REQUEST['cm']);
            $transid = explode(":", $cm);
            $transactionid = $transid[2];
            $buyerid = $transid[0];
            $transcookie = $transid[3];
            $who = fetch_userinfo($buyerid);
            $buyername = $who['username'];
            $buyeremail = $who['email'];
            $transamount = sprintf('%.2f', $transamount);
            $mcgross = number_format(doubleval($_POST['mc_gross']), 2);
            if ($item_name != 'renewal' and $transamount)
            {

                $verify = $db->query_first("SELECT amount FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX .
                    "covercartfraud WHERE transactionid='" . $transid[2] . "' AND userid='" . $buyerid .
                    "'");
                if ($verify['amount'] <> $transamount)
                {
                    $file = fopen($config['log'] . $_REQUEST['tx'] . '.datatrans', "w", 0);
                    fputs($file, "POSSIBLE FRAUD IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " FROM PAYPAL: " .
                        $transamount . " VBCART TRANSACTION ID: " . $transid[2] . " USERID: " . $buyerid .
                        " FROM DB: " . $verify['amount'] . "\n");
                    fclose($file);

                    eval(standard_error(fetch_error('covercart_invalidamount')));
                }
            }
```

It goes on a little further, but I feel the part I need to focus on is right at the top. since that's where it communicates with PayPal.

When I submit to PayPal it sends me to `https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=3986eaa08f5be&code=AMOUNT_ERROR` and states `Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.`

I have made the following changes, updating the headers and adding trim in 2 places (I thought were correct) yet I am still receiving this error when I attempt to checkout.

```
$headerx .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$headerx .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($request) . "\r\n";
$headerx .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$headerx .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$headerx .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    //$sock = fsockopen('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    $sock = fsockopen( 'tls://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$sock)
    {
        $file = fopen($config['log'] . $_REQUEST['tx'] . '.datatrans', "w", 0);
        fputs($file, "HTTP ERROR\n");
        fclose($file);
        eval('$cartinfo .= "' . fetch_template('covercart_orderfailure') . '";');
    } else
    {
        fputs($sock, $headerx . $request);
        // read the body data
        $result = '';
        $headerdone = false;

        while (!feof($sock))
        {
            $line = fgets($sock, 1024);

            if (strcmp(trim($line), "\r\n") == 0)
            {
                // read the header
                $headerdone = true;
            } else
                if ($headerdone)
                {
                    // header has been read. now read the contents
                    $result .= $line;
                }
        }

        // parse the data
        $lines = explode("\n", $result);
        $keyarray = array();

        if (!strcmp(trim($lines[0]), "SUCCESS") == 0)
```

Where am I going wrong for the communication between my site and PayPal?

UPDATE:
I dug into the `AMOUNT_ERROR` I noticed in the url (which seemed suspicious) and discovered my input was submitting `$1.00` when it needed to be sending `1.00` removing the `$` allowed the process to go through.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given script? Why not use any of the existing libraries?

Comment: I am unable to locate an Auth token ( I can only find Client ID & Client Secret in my PayPal dashboard) so the variable does not get filled.  So when I try to checkout I am redirected to paypal and the page says `Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.` because I am missing the Auth Token

Comment: As for updating, this is a full fledge store product, and I just don't know where to begin updating it with a new library.

Comment: There's more wrong here than just your PayPal interface. Your code uses `eval()`, which is inherently dangerous, and it also uses concatenated queries which are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be building a business case for a major overhaul.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I will address that when I have something functioning, as for the original question I have re phrased and updated with one of my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

It's very broad question, so my answer will be broad to.

From `$request = 'cmd=_notify-synch';` until `$lines = explode("\n", $result);` it's an API call to PayPal. So maybe you can start by looking up that call in the PayPal documentation. And replace that peace of code by the PayPal PHP SDK. That library will contain information about authentication and I assume that will tell you where to put the client ID and secret.

Comment: Upon further digging I discovered the "auth token" it needs is actually a business accounts identity token.  I have updated the settings to use my token, yet still recieve the same error.

Comment: I have re phrased the original question, and updated with one of my attempts

Comment: Calling an API like this is very error prone. I’ll suggest using the PayPal SDK. Or if you can’t use that try to refactor it to curl.